# HTML CSS hints for a design

Tags: html, css

First of all, I am sorry if these kinds of questions are not encouraged here, but I am really confused about how to post this as a constructive question. So please, bear with me :D

I am trying to make a blog that looks something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hongkiat.com](http://media02.hongkiat.com/blog-design-styles/crayonslife.jpg))</sub>

I can make this in CSS with some hit and trial but I am confused how to do this if I want "a Crayon's Life" to go in the same `h1`. Any hints? Thanks!

EDIT: I am not going to include the picture, it that matters. Also, no IE<9 support required

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible, also it is not very clear what is `nav to go in a single nav`

Comment: Oops, I don't know why I write that `:/`

Comment: You can use [CSS Shapes](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/) or the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) CSS attribute to define a custom shape for your element.

Comment: this can be a possible approach if the content doesn't change : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/zee21cea/

Comment: this is an other possible approach : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/zee21cea/1/

Comment: Thanks for all this help guys! I was thinking maybe I should add "a crayon's <span>life</span>" in `h1` and hide the span, then add `life` above content area without any h1, it'll still work great for crawlers and will be easier to make the website fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a line break inside the header, set the indentation so that there's spacing before the second line, and move the navigation up.

```
<h1>A Crayon's <br> Life</h1>
<ul>
    <li>illustrations</li>
    <li>web design</li>
    <li>etc.</li>    
    <li>etc.</li>
</ul>
```

```
h1 {
    padding-left: 150px;
    text-indent: -150px;
}

ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqxeqh62/)

Set the pixel values as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML tags inside an `h1` as longs as it's semantics are correct.
Basically:

```
<h1>
    <span>a</span>
    <strong>Crayon's</strong>
    <span>life</span>
</h1>
```

This is considered to be still OK for SEO, semantics, CSS markup.
The trial and error to get this right, layout wise, is still the work to be done by you I assume.

Something along the lines of:

```
h1 { position: relative; }
h1 span { color: orange; }
h1 strong { color: red; }
h1 strong + span { position: absolute; top: 50px; left: auto/*or in px*/ }
```